# hibernate - uniqueResult silently fails

Tags: hibernate, spring, tomcat

I have a login controller that use the hibernate uniqueResult method. Everything works fine when i test it in eclipse's tomcat server. But when i deploy my webapps to tomcat server (on the same machine) it fails: it always returns null even i use the correct credential.

Here is my hibernate code:

```
session.createCriteria(User.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq(User.USERNAME_FIELD, userName))
            .add(Restrictions.eq(User.PASSWORD_FIELD, password)).uniqueResult();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Everything looks fine, i guess the User does not exist.

Comment: `uniqueResult()` is not "silently failing". The Hibernate API clearly says that `uniqueResult()` will return null if the query returns no results (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#uniqueResult%28%29)

Comment: As a side note. Shouldn't you at least hash the password?

Comment: As mentioned by @skaffman the uniqueResult() API javadoc method does state that null will be returned if no results are found. Here is a link to the current (4.3) API documentation page: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#uniqueResult%28%29

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should try to see the actual hibernate query and parameters using the logger. The two loggers you should make to "debug" are:

- `org.hibernate.SQL`
- `org.hibernate.type`

Put both on `TRACE` or `ALL` and check the result on logging. For more information about the logger see [the hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging).

The most common case would be log4j. AFAIK, `hibernate.show_sql` is deprecated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration>
<appender name="Stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate.type">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Stdout"/>
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information, try to trace the SQL that is being generated:

Set in `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Or set these Hibernate properties

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Then try to run these queries, with the passed parameters that return null directly in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this problem by adding `session.flush()`.

Comment: To help you, please do what we suggested and add it to your question (the generated logs), and also the full context of your code

Comment: when i add the log4j dependency, i see in my eclipse's tomcat console, the webapp is constantly reload and it ended up being "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space"

I dont know how to solve this :-(

Comment: A need for session.flush() when reading something from the database seems rather odd. I guess you do mean another place in your codebase, where you actually save stuff, don't you?

Comment: @robinmag - PermGen: add -XX:MaxPermSize=256m